# How to disable everything in crontab -l?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I just want to pause everything.  Don't execute anything listed on `crontab -l`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`crontab -e` then comment out each line you don't want to run with `#`.

Comment: Try this with 100 jobs ...

Comment: @merlin Use column edit move in vi/vim

Answer (score 198):

First, back up the crontab:

```
crontab -l > my_cron_backup.txt
```

Then you can empty it:

```
crontab -r
```

To restore:

```
crontab my_cron_backup.txt
crontab -l
```

This works only for the crontab of the user who runs these commands, but it does not empty/restore crontabs of other users. My [other answer](https://serverfault.com/a/734210/9461) is about suspending launches from all the users.

Comment: This is particularly helpful when `/tmp` is corrupted (and if your crontab -e uses `mktemp` in `/tmp`.

Comment: If you are running your cronjobs in sudo better make sure you sudo first when backing up so you get the right one.

Answer (score 84):

Do you have root access?  Just pause cron

```
sudo /etc/init.d/crond stop
```

Then restart it when you're ready

```
sudo /etc/init.d/crond start
```

Comment: That is assuming you want to stop crontab for all users including root. The selected answer, and kubanskamac's answer would do it for just the current (desired?) user.

Comment: our crond service had been stopped.  This pointed us in right direction to check whether crond was running, and restart.

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu you can use `sudo service cron stop`

Comment: On Debian this is `/etc/init.d/cron stop`.

Comment: @Faheem on Debian nowadays it’s also `service cron stop`.

Comment: on centos i did `systemctl stop crond.service`

Comment: I get `sudo: /etc/init.d/crond: command not found`

Answer (score 13):

If you are using vi as editor, then just enter `:%s/^/#/` in command mode. In all lines (%), it substitutes (s///) the begin of line (^) with a hash (#).

Comment: If you are not using vi as default editor, you can "force" usage of vi like `EDITOR=vi; crontab -e`, and than you can use the trick above.

Comment: To uncomment, command is `:%s/^#//`

Answer (score 6):

Wasn't happy with the options above since they weren't one liners.

**To disable** `crontab -l | perl -nle 's/^([^#])/# $1/;print' | crontab`

**To enable**  `crontab -l | perl -nle 's/^#\s*([0-9*])/$1/;print' | crontab`

usage example ( edited to show it doesn't disable comments)

```
$ crontab -l
# Comment
0 0 * * 0 /opt/something.sh

$ crontab -l|perl -nle 's/^([^#])/# $1/;print'|crontab
$ crontab -l
# Comment
# 0 0 * * 0 /opt/something.sh

$ crontab -l|perl -nle 's/^#\s*([0-9*])/$1/;print'|crontab
$ crontab -l
# Comment
0 0 * * 0 /opt/something.sh
```

Tested this on RHEL and AIX , and should work out of the box without anything needed to be installed

Comment: Also can look for specific details in the cronjob     crontab -l | perl -nle 's/^#\s*([0-1*])/$1/;print if /.+mytexttofind.+/'

Comment: Could you please explain why comments are not affected? What is the pattern you use to detect them?

Comment: Hm, under Debian Jessie I get the following error: `crontab: usage error: file name must be specified for replace`. It seems you have to specify a file (?) when using `crontab` without any parameters (which is `replace` by default).

Comment: @Sopalajo de Arrierez If the first character after #/space is a digit 0-9, then it should be a cron scheduling, and we have to drop the pound sign. This is because the comments mainly start with a word. Unfortunately, this will fail with a comment like this: "# 2 do the backups".

Comment: @fritzmg I suggest that the pseudo-filename - (dash as standard input) needs to be self-explanatory : `[..];print' | crontab  -`

Answer (score 3):

In my limited testing, setting the shell to /bin/false works.  You will still see `/opt/job.sh` executing in your logs, but it will be a noop:

```
SHELL=/bin/false

*/1 * * * *    root  /some/job.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

In any flavor of Unix/Linux that I know of (except maybe OpenBSD):

```
mv /var/spool/cron  /var/spool/cron_is_disabled
```

This:

- disables crontabs of all users
- but not system /etc/crontab (/etc/cron.daily. etc.)
- persists across a reboot
- is a one-liner, duh :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the idea from the answer provided by @segaps

To disable:

```
crontab -l | awk '{print "# "$1}' | crontab
```

To enable:

```
crontab -l | cut -c 3- | crontab
```

The only problem with the solution provided by segaps, is that it will uncomment the jobs, that are already commented by the user.

Comment: Disable command should be: crontab -l | awk '{print "# "$0}' | crontab

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following like so:

```
crondisable
cronenable

crondisable some_other_user
...
```

The `zsh` code (put in your `.zshrc`):

```
ecerr () {
print -r -- "$@" >&2
}
crondisable() {
        local user="${1:-$(whoami)}"
        local cronpath="/tmp/$user.cron.tmp"
        test -e "$cronpath" && {
        ecerr "There is already a disabled crontab at $cronpath. Remove that manually if you want to proceed."
        return 1
        }
        crontab -l -u $user > "$cronpath"
        crontab -r -u $user
}
cronenable() {
        local user="${1:-$(whoami)}"
        local cronpath="/tmp/$user.cron.tmp"
        test -e "$cronpath" || {
        ecerr "No disabled cron at $cronpath"
        return 1
        }
        crontab -u $user "$cronpath"
        mv "$cronpath" "${cronpath}.bak"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To do this, using nano as the editor:

```
sudo env EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

then comment out each line you don't want to run with #